# On complemented copy of $c_{0}$ in projective tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Suppose that the projective tensor product of $l_{\infty}$ and $X$ contains a complemented copy of $c_{0}$. Does it follow that $X$ contains a complemented copy of $c_{0}$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. In fact, by the main theorem of G. Emmanuele, 
 "On complemented copies of $c_{0}$ in $L_{X}^p$, $1 \leq p< \infty$",  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 104, 1988, 3, 785-786, it follows that the projective tensor product of $l_{\infty}$ and $L_{1}$ contains  a complemented copy of $c_{0}$.